# How do I change cloud nine back to mr.cuddles?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I went into the stash choose equip on the new cloud nine machine. I want to change it back to mr.cuddles but it doesn't have a unequip button and I can't figure out how to change it to me.cuddles

Answer (score 1):

You go into the shop, go into the Vehicle Upgrades menu, scroll down to the Mr. Cuddles section and press your desired Mr. Cuddles skin (the normal Mr. Cuddles in your case) afterwards the tab will expand, revealing an "equip" button, press it and you're done.